# Random distribution of boys and girls into groups c#

Tags: c#, list, math, random

Similar questions have been asked before, but not answered the way I can work with it.

I have groups of 3, 4, 5 and 6 and each group is supposed to be filled with 50% boys and 50% girls. The user determines the amount of each group as well as the number of boys and girls.

For instance: 12 girls, 15 boys, 1*3, 2*4, 2*5 and 1*6 groups.

I already have an instance of `Random`. How I can now put the randomly chosen boys/girls equally into the groups?

Random for boys and group of 4:

```
//for each group of 4
for (int i = 0; i < tischgruppenVierer; i++)
{
    //only do this two times because 50% boys
    for (int j = 0; j < 4/2; j++)
    {
        var picked = namesBoys[random.Next(0, namesBoys.Count())];
        namesBoys.Remove(picked); //no duplicates
        picked = new TischVier().student;
    }
}
```

and the class `TischVier`:

```
public class TischVier
{
    public string student;
}
```

I hope this is enough code for you because I hardcoded it for every group.
I appreciate every thought because I am close to despair.

Comment: Your requirements still require clarification. Try to edit your question and clarify your needs. Your code is not helpful.

Comment: How can you fill a group of 3 with 50% boys and 50% girls?

Comment: @DStanley this is my next problem

Comment: Cant you just randomly order the list of boys and the list of girls, and then pick one from each, in an alternating pattern? (BTW this also solves the problem stated above)

Comment: I assume the odd groups would have 1 more of the gender with more members? e.g. if there are more boys than girls, the groups of 3 would be (b,b,g) and the groups of 5 would be (b,b,b,g,g) ?

Comment: @zackraiyan The variables `namesBoys` is just all the boys in a list and `tischgruppenVierer` is the number of groups of 4. They got passed via the constructor to the class. Is that enough, because the code behind that is too long to post.

Comment: The question is unclear, what should happen if there are 10 girls and 1 boy? else just put one boy after one girl in a group?

Comment: The last line doesn't make sense at all, maybe you want a `new TischVier()` with `student = picked`? You then have to keep the instance `TischVier` you've just created or it gets lost. So, maybe something like: `TischVier t = new TischVier(); t.student = picked; alleTische.Add(t);` mit `alleTische = new List<TischVier>();`??

Comment: @Jamiec awesome thought. How would that pattern look like? All that math has destroyed my mind...

Comment: @pid True this was also incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap this up in class containing your 2 lists (boys & girls) along with a method to get a group of specified size. In pseudo code this method goes:

1. Shuffle list of boys & list of girls
2. Initialize a boolean switch to flip/flop between boys and girls
3. Count up to the required size, for each iteration....
4. Pop a boy or girl off the list according to boolean flag
5. Flip the boolean

In real code, that looks something like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetGroup(int size)
{
    Shuffle(boys);
    Shuffle(girls);
    if((boys.Count + girls.Count) < size)
    {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not enough people to satisfy group");
    }
    bool isBoy = rng.NextDouble() > 0.5;
    for(var i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        string next = "";
        if(isBoy)
        {
            yield return PopBoy();
        }
        else
        {
            yield return PopGirl();
        }
        isBoy = !isBoy;
    }
}
```

To make this all work you need to check there is enough capacity in both lists for the required group (see exception thrown above).

There is an extra complexity; maybe the list of boys or girls is exhausted. You should pop the other one if this is the case.

```
private string PopBoy()
{
    if(boys.Count>0)
    {
        var name = boys[0];
        boys.RemoveAt(0);
        return name;
    }
    else
    {
        return PopGirl();
    }
}
private string PopGirl()
{
    if(girls.Count>0)
    {
        var name = girls[0];
        girls.RemoveAt(0);
        return name;
    }
    else
    {
        return PopBoy();
    }
}
```

Fully working code can be found here: https://rextester.com/DKYCMN49734

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the code for more info:

```
//setup

//hold the group sizes we want to make - you say your user chose this
int[] groupSizes = new[] {3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6};

//you have lists of people from somewhere
List<Person> boys = new List<Person>();
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  boys.Add(new Person());
List<Person> girls = new List<Person>();
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  girls.Add(new Person());

//logic of random grouping
List<List<Person>> groups = new List<List<Person>>();
Random r = new Random();

bool takeBoy = false;

//for each groupsize we make
foreach(int g in groupSizes){ 

  List<Person> group = new List<Person>(); //new group
  for(int i = 0; i < g; i++){ //take people, up to group size

    //take boys and girls alternately
    takeBoy = !takeBoy;
    var fr = takeBoy ? boys : girls;

    //if there are no more boys/girls, take other gender instead
    if(fr.Count == 0) 
      fr = takeBoy ? girls : boys;

    //choose a person at random, less than list length
    var ri = r.Next(fr.Count);

    //add to the current grouping
    group.Add(fr[ri]);

    //remove from consideration
    fr.RemoveAt(ri);
  }
  //group is made, store in the groups list
  groups.Add(group);
}
```

And demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KS7HFb using "always take boy first" logic

Another demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/68YFYf using "global alternate boy/girl taking" logic

Comment: I think having a global counter or ensuring a flipping every time instead just by inside of the group is better because it will produce more even distribution. Assume that groups sizes are `3,3,4`. AFAIU you code will produce the last group of the same gender (`2+1, 2+1, 0+4`) instead of a much better `2+1, 1+2, 2+2` distribution.